# Switch sections in Helm

Tags: helm

I've been running into a problem with Helm recently with `ispell`. If I run `ispell-change-dictionary` first to set the dictionary, I can't figure out how to run `ispell` afterward through `helm-M-x`. The problem is that `ispell-change-dictionary` shows up in the `Emacs Commands History` section, and I can't figure out how to get down to the `Emacs Commands` list below that. `C-n` just moves within the commands history and never moves down.

Comment: Did you try pressing `C-o` or the "right" key? (This calls `helm-next-source`.)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/27645582

Comment: @Constantine. Ah. That is the ticket. Not sure why that didn't pop up in my searches.